# EXC_BREAKPOINT UNKNOWN crash on line "0"

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I have this strange crash in Crashlytics report and I'm not sure what's going on. I don't even know what does the line number "0" means. Any ideas?

[image]

Code from didSelect method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.section {

    case 1:
        let vc = WTShowDetailVC()
        vc.show = bottomFeaturedShows[indexPath.row].show
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    case 2:
        let vc = WTShowDetailVC()
        vc.show = lastWatchedShows[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    case 3:
        let vc = WTTapperProfileUserVC()
        vc.tapper = popularTappers[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    default:
        println("Something went wrong")
    }
}
```

Comment: Try navigationController!.pushViewController instead of navigationController?.pushViewController  It is not about line 0 anyway.

Comment: Just like @user3344236 said, its not about line 0, also make sure you aren't accessing an array object out of index.

Comment: Hmm, I believe my version is correct. "navigationController?" is safer than "navigationController!". I think the issue is not related to navigationController.

Comment: @Schemetrical Sure. If the problem was there, I'd get "out of bounds" issue. What I get is "EXC_BREAKPOINT UNKNOWN"

Comment: ok, check if bottomFeaturedShows[indexPath.row] or lastWatchedShows[indexPath.row] or popularTappers[indexPath.row] is nil [null]. I think your problem is in line bottomFeaturedShows[indexPath.row].show

Comment: @VojtaStavik did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Please show how you declare `tapper`, and `show` variables.

Comment: Did you figure it out now?

Comment: I didn't. Do you have a similar issue? I think, in my case, it was more related to not 100% accurate crash reports for Swift.

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when you are unwrapping an optional and it's value is `nil`. Try putting a `nil` check to `navigationController`.

```
if let navigationcontroller: UINavigationController = navigationController { 
    navigationcontroller.pushViewController(vc, animated: true) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it can't be this issue. Calling navigationController?.pushViewController is correct and won't result to crash is navigationController is nil.

Comment: I faced similar scenarios. In my case, the scenario was reproducible. The crash was not on the same line as given on the crashlytics report. I suggest you to check if there are any optionals inside the functions that you are using i.e, bottomFeaturedShows, lastWatchedShows etc.

Comment: It's not necessarily about optionals per se. In my case, the crash was a result of setting a swift non-optional object with an object in Objective-C, which was `nil`